# Jquery File Upload SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I want use prduct but when upload image i see error

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data**

```
script directory: Folder2
directory Jquery-file-upload: function/blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload/
in main.js i edit rows

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
// Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
//xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
url: 'server/php/'
});
```

on

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
// Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
//xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
url: '../function/blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload/server/php/'
});
```

Image true save on server, but error with show him after upload.

**Step1**
http://s55.radikal.ru/i149/1211/10/8c8d911589de.jpg

**Step2 with error**
http://s019.radikal.ru/i604/1211/8c/7e05d92b30ef.jpg

**furebug response to a request**

```
[{"name":"1353755388.jpg","size":879394,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"http:\/\/malish-ka.ru\/function\/blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload\/server\/php\/files\/1353755388.jpg","thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/malish-ka.ru\/function\/blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload\/server\/php\/files\/thumbnail\/1353755388.jpg","upload_to_db":true,"delete_url":"http:\/\/malish-ka.ru\/function\/blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload\/server\/php\/?file=ExPRoG-1353755388.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]/home/m/malishkaru/public_html/function/blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload/server/php
```

**Tell me please why i have this error? When error?**

Comment: The "response to a request" that you show is not valid JSON because of the text after the closing `]`. If you can change your PHP to _not_ return everything after the closing `]` you'll have valid JSON. The "unexpected non-whitespace character" is the `/` in `/home/m/etc` after the closing `]`.

Answer (score 3):

The "response to a request" that you show is not valid JSON because of the text after the closing ].

If you can change your PHP to not return everything after the closing ] you'll have valid JSON.

The "unexpected non-whitespace character" is the / in /home/m/etc after the closing ]

I delete part code when write **/home/m/malishkaru/public_html/function/blueimp-jQuery-File-Upload/server/php** and all worked.

P.S.: thanks **nnnnnn**.

P.P.S.: answer for close question only. user **nnnnnn** give good answer.

Comment: Please what part did you delete ?