# Image uploading using ajax gives non-whitespace character after JSON data?

Tags: php, json, image

I am getting this error while uploading image using ajax,

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

I googled, but not found any appropriate answer,

Here is my ajax function,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image').on('change', function(){
        $("#frm_name").ajaxForm({
            success: function(data) {
                res = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(res.status === 1){
                    alert('success');
                    var html = "<img src='<?=base_url();?>' + 'public/images/' + '"+res.image_name+"' class='preview' width='100' height='100' />";
                        $("#preview").html(html);
                        $("#frm_name").ajaxFormUnbind();
                }
                if(res.status === 0){
                    $("#frm_name").ajaxFormUnbind();
                }
            }
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

On the other side, i am encoding as,

```
echo json_encode(array('status'=>1, 'image_name'=>$this->upload->file_name));
```

and response is,

```
{"status":1,"image_name":"b_nD4nS1.jpg"}
```

Image is uploading successfuly, i am getting correct response, but not showing, even i tried to alert something,
Please help,

Comment: you can check your whole Json response is valid or not. http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/

Comment: i have checked, its absolutely right

Comment: can you please post your full json response here.

Comment: you can refer this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541107/jquery-file-upload-syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-non-whitespace-character

Comment: solved=), i was getting some html under this response, and i was suppposing the correct response, i removed that html, it worked!